# Logistic regression with intercept only

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I need to fit a logistic regression with sklearn, but with no x vector, just the model with intercept, how can it be done? I cannot find any working solution.

Thanks

Edit: I want to find alternative solution in sklearn for R's regression y ~ 1.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean you want to fit a logistic regression to some data, then return only the intercept of the model? It would help greatly if you would [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including sample input, desired output, and code for what you've tried so far

Comment: I guess you could simulate this by passing in a vector of `np.ones(y_train.shape)` as your x_train and then set `fit_intercept` to `False` when you call `fit`. What is your motivation for this though? Won't it just return `np.mean(y_train)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to run a logit Only on the intercept, so, I created one constant column and ran the model without the intercept.

```
import nmpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
### Create the data
a = np.array([1] * 20 + [0] * 180)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['y'])
df['intercept'] = 1
## Conduct the Logit Regression analysis
logmodel = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False)
logit_result = logmodel.fit(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['y'])],df['y'])
#### Print the coefficient
print(logit_result.intercept_)
print(logit_result.coef_)
```